# Root Partition using too much space

Tags: partitioning, mount, root, disk-usage, lvm

I'm having problems with my disk usage. My system monitor says that I have 44,6gb used. But when I run disk usage analyzer, it shows that I have 5.4gb used. My partitions are in LVM. Here some images:

[image: System Monitor]

[image: Disk Usage Analyser]

Here the `df -a` result too:

```
Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 110437200 43584168  61220020  42% /
proc                                0        0         0    - /proc
sysfs                               0        0         0    - /sys
none                                4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                                0        0         0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
none                                0        0         0    - /sys/kernel/debug
none                                0        0         0    - /sys/kernel/security
none                                0        0         0    - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
udev                          4016416        4   4016412   1% /dev
devpts                              0        0         0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                          806336     1084    805252   1% /run
none                             5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none                          4031680      164   4031516   1% /run/shm
none                           102400       48    102352   1% /run/user
none                                0        0         0    - /sys/fs/pstore
/dev/sda2                      241965    54091    175382  24% /boot
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-home 361112164 38376484 304369216  12% /home
/dev/sda1                      523248     3428    519820   1% /boot/efi
binfmt_misc                         0        0         0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
systemd                             0        0         0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
/home/marcus/.Private       361112164 38376484 304369216  12% /home/marcus
gvfsd-fuse                          0        0         0    - /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

With additional info I resize the root partition to get the Home partition.

In advance, thanks for all the help. I wanna to know what is causing this difference and how i solve this issue.

Comment: Sorry to be pendantic, but what is your question? Please [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/548131/edit) and ask what you want to know.

Comment: Sorry for not be clear. My question is why my system monitor says that i`m using 44GB and my disk usage 5.5GB. I`m not sure that i`m using all this space in root partition. Is like the root partition kept the disk usage that he had before the partition.

Comment: @MarcusLima You have a triangle next to  the /usr/ directory, you can click on it, and see the subdirectories and their 'weight'. This may provide some information as to what is using this data. It can be many things, you could have installed something like bitcoin application or gnunet or many other things.

Comment: Please don't put your answer inside the question and put "solved" in the title. Write the answer below where it says "Your Answer". Then you can put a green check mark next to your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i had resized my ROOT volume and copied my Home files to my HOME volume, the 'rm' not erased my encrypted files. I just boot my system with a live CD, mounted my /root volume and use 'rm -f' to erase all files inside the home folder in /root.Thus, the hidden folder .encrptfs was deleted.